# How do I mix MVC views and ASPX pages inside the same folder?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How can I tell to MVC routing that `company.com/store/bank_account` should load `company.com/store/bank_account/default.aspx` instead of a MVC view?

Thanks.

Comment: It is not a good practice to mix MVC and Webforms.

Comment: How do you show hundreds of static pages in MVC with the Login link on the top/right corner? Making a view for each one?

Comment: You did not mentioned about any static pages in the question. If you wish to repeat a login link on each page, you can use master pages in mvc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using IgnoreRoute. You can set this in the global.asax like this

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");
```

check out this 
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/07/14/make-routing-ignore-requests-for-a-file-extension.aspx

and

http://www.packtpub.com/article/mixing-asp.net-webforms-and-asp.net-mvc

Comment: I don't see how IgnoreRoute is going to handle mapping an extensionless url like `/store/bank_account` to an aspx path. IgnoreRoute makes it easy to hit the page *with* the extension, but that wasn't really the question. +1 for good info, though.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a rewrite engine, such as [Helicon's ISAPI Rewrite](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/). Or, if you're using IIS7 or above, you can use [Microsoft's URL rewriter](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite).

Or, since you already have an MVC app in place, you can use [a method like this one](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/11/using-routing-with-webforms.aspx) to use routing for your webforms pages.

[This article](http://chriscavanagh.wordpress.com/2008/03/11/aspnet-routing-goodbye-url-rewriting/), linked to from the one above, provides a handy class to help with your scenario.

*Code reproduced here because links sometimes disappear*

```
public class WebFormRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
{
  public WebFormRouteHandler(string virtualPath) : this(virtualPath, true)
  {
  }

  public WebFormRouteHandler(string virtualPath, bool checkPhysicalUrlAccess)
  {
    this.VirtualPath = virtualPath;
    this.CheckPhysicalUrlAccess = checkPhysicalUrlAccess;
  }

  public string VirtualPath { get; private set; }

  public bool CheckPhysicalUrlAccess { get; set; }

  public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
  {
    if (this.CheckPhysicalUrlAccess 
      && !UrlAuthorizationModule.CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal(this.VirtualPath
              ,  requestContext.HttpContext.User
              , requestContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod))
      throw new SecurityException();

    var page = BuildManager
      .CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(this.VirtualPath
        , typeof(Page)) as IHttpHandler;

    if (page != null)
    {
      var routablePage = page as IRoutablePage;
      if (routablePage != null)
        routablePage.RequestContext = requestContext;
    }
    return page;
  }
}
```

You'd use that when registering your routes in `Global.asax.cs`.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes( RouteCollection routes )
{
    // Note: Change the URL to "{controller}.mvc/{action}/{id}" to enable
    //       automatic support on IIS6 and IIS7 classic mode

    var routeHandler = new WebFormRouteHandler<Page>( "~/MyPage.aspx" );

    routes.Add( new Route( "{page}", routeHandler ) );
    routes.Add( new Route( "AccountServices/{page}", routeHandler ) );
    routes.Add( new Route( "Default.aspx", routeHandler ) );
}
```