# Having ASPX, HTM and MVC views in the same folder

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

We liked the approach to have all the pages regarding support - for example - under `http://www.company.com/support`. After migrating to ASP.NET MVC 3 and trying [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113143/how-do-i-mix-mvc-views-and-aspx-pages-inside-the-same-folder) we can run every type of page but not inside the same folder.

Is there any workaround for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to mix MVC pages and non-MVC pages in the same folder, here's some tips:

Remove the default route `"/{controller}/{action}/{id}"` and make routes for each MVC page. That way any request that isn't caught by a route falls through to the "old" request handling.

A `return View();` method call in a controller looks for a view in a folder named as the controller in the `Views` folder, so specify the name of the view, e.g. `return View("/support/index");`.

Note that the MVC views doesn't actually have to be in the folder `support`, you can put them anywhere you like, it's the routes that determine which URLs are handled by MVC.

Comment: Thanks Guffa: it would be great to look for legacy pages if no views are found under that name.

Comment: @devdept: I don't know if that is possible. The MVC engine is not looking for views when determining if any route matches, only the actual routes. A controller can use any view it likes (or no view at all), so there doesn't have to be a view that corresponds to the request.